# Deleting a row in R using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, row

I'm looking to be able to delete a row from a data frame already uploaded to r. I tried using the "select(Dataframe, -c(...)" function part of the dplyr package but this only deletes columns and not rows.

```
library(dplyr)
WallyceEdited <- select(X0626Wallyce,-c(Intensity,Signal, Ambient))

head(WallyceEdited)
```

The code used above is great for deleting columns, but I am wondering if there is a similar function I can use in dplyr or tidyverse to delete rows, not just columns.

Comment: Are you looking for `?dplyr::filter` or `?dplyr::slice` maybe?

Comment: Are you trying to delete based on a condition or position? Both should be covered thoroughly on SO, but which one you need will help point you to previous posts

Answer (score 2):

This removes the third row where `BOD` is a builtin data frame with 6 rows that comes with R:

```
library(dplyr)
BOD %>% slice(-3)
```

giving this 5 row data frame:

```
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    4   16.0
4    5   15.6
5    7   19.8
```